# Pointers being substituted by last pointer call?

Tags: c, pointers

What happens is that the program prints the multiplication of the quantity of macronutrients (carbs, fats and proteins) by their calorie density.

All is well up to this part of the code, however, when I try to sum the results, for some reason the code instead substitutes all the previous pointers by the last one (prot_ptr).

This is the source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CARB_CAL 4
#define PROT_CAL 4
#define FAT_CAL 9

int *fat_ptr;
int *prot_ptr;
int *carb_ptr;

void ask_name(void);
void ask_fat(void);
void ask_carb(void);
void ask_prot(void);

// main function
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // food name 
    ask_name();
    ask_fat();
    ask_carb();
    ask_prot();

    int sum = *fat_ptr + *carb_ptr + *prot_ptr;
    printf("total calories: %d\n", sum);
}

void ask_name(void)
{
    char *name;
    printf("input the name of the meal item: ");
    name = malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
    scanf("%s", name);  
    printf("\nMEAL NAME: %s\n", name);
    free(name);
}

// fats
void ask_fat(void)
{
    int fat;
    printf("\ninput the quantity of fat: ");
    scanf("%d", &fat); 
    printf("\n");
    printf("fat calories: %d\n",  (fat * FAT_CAL));

    int int_fat = (fat * FAT_CAL);
    fat_ptr = &int_fat;
}

// carbs
void ask_carb(void)
{
    int carb;
    printf("\ninput the quantity of carbs: ");
    scanf("%d", &carb); 
    printf("\n");
    printf("carb calories: %d\n",  (carb * CARB_CAL));

    int int_carb = (carb * CARB_CAL);
    carb_ptr = &int_carb;
}

// proteins
void ask_prot(void)
{
    int prot;
    printf("\ninput the quantity of protein: ");
    scanf("%d", &prot); 
    printf("\n");
    printf("protein calories: %d\n",  (prot * PROT_CAL));

    int int_prot = (prot * PROT_CAL);
    prot_ptr = &int_prot;
}
```

And this is an example output:

> ./learn input the name of the meal item: rice
>
> MEAL NAME: rice
>
> input the quantity of fat: 1
>
> fat calories: 9
>
> input the quantity of carbs: 12
>
> carb calories: 48
>
> input the quantity of protein: 3
>
> protein calories: 12
>
> total calories: 36

The desired result would be the sum 9 + 48 + 12, but what the program does is, it sums 12 + 12 + 12.

Comment: Don't return address of temporary variable, this causes undefined behavior. Make global variables non-pointers and your code should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying address of temporary variables to the global pointers. This causes undefined behavior when the pointer is later accesed.

Since your functions return only one value, you can consider using return value of functions and computing the sum as the total sum:

```
int ask_fat(void)
{
    int fat;
    printf("\ninput the quantity of fat: ");
    scanf("%d", &fat);

    fat = fat * FAT_CAL;
    printf("\nfat calories: %d\n", fat);

    return fat;
}
```

Do the same for the rest of your functions and then compute summary in `main` as follows:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ask_name();

    int sum = ask_fat() + ask_carb() + ask_prot();
    printf("total calories: %d\n", sum);
}
```

Or if you really need to use global variables, then just simply change them to non-pointers and save the value in respective `ask_` function. But please note global variables are not neccessary in this case so it's better to avoid them.

Comment: `printf("\nfat calories: %d\n", fat);` why using 2 printf when only one is needed? (not a big change tho)

Answer (score 1):

Do you must work with pointer? Pointer are source of problems. I would rater use function that return an int then manipulate pointer adress. Here is a code that work for what you're doing. If you really need to use pointer, i'll edit it without taking the temporary variable adress.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CARB_CAL 4
#define PROT_CAL 4
#define FAT_CAL 9

int fat;
int prot;
int carb;

void ask_name(void);
int ask_fat(void);
int ask_carb(void);
int ask_prot(void);

// main function                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  // food name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  ask_name();
  fat = ask_fat();
  carb = ask_carb();
  prot = ask_prot();

  int sum = fat + carb + prot;
  printf("total calories: %d\n", sum);
}

void ask_name(void)
{
  char *name;
  printf("input the name of the meal item: ");
  name = malloc(6 * sizeof(char));
  scanf("%s", name);
  printf("\nMEAL NAME: %s\n", name);
  free(name);
}

// fats                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
int ask_fat(void)
{
  int fat;
  printf("\ninput the quantity of fat: ");
  scanf("%d", &fat);
  printf("\nfat calories: %d\n",  (fat * FAT_CAL));

  int int_fat = (fat * FAT_CAL);
  return int_fat;
}

// carbs                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
int ask_carb(void)
{
  int carb;
  printf("\ninput the quantity of carbs: ");
  scanf("%d", &carb);
  printf("\ncarb calories: %d\n",  (carb * CARB_CAL));

  int int_carb = (carb * CARB_CAL);
  return int_carb;
}
```